# loading a new page when scrolling to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm setting up a website for a friend. I'm learning by doing. I already made a landing page which plays an animation when the user scrolls the page. I'd like to load the main page when the user scrolls through the whole animation.

I already tried it this way ([How to load a new page/url when user reach the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307676/how-to-load-a-new-page-url-when-user-reach-the-bottom)) but it didn't work.

```
 <div id="set-height"></div>

    <video id="v0" tabindex="0", autobuffer preload>
        <source type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' src="CircleShortKopie.mp4"></source>
    </video>


    <script>
var frameNumber = 0, // start video at frame 0
  // lower numbers = faster playback
  playbackConst = 1000,

  // get page height from video duration
  setHeight = document.getElementById("set-height"),
  // select video element         
  vid = document.getElementById('v0');

// var vid = $('#v0')[0]; // jquery option
// dynamically set the page height according to video length
vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  setHeight.style.height = Math.floor(vid.duration) * playbackConst + "px";
});
// Use requestAnimationFrame for smooth playback
function scrollPlay() {
  var frameNumber = window.pageYOffset / playbackConst;
  vid.currentTime = frameNumber;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How I can load the next page after scrolling through the animation?